# Rook and minor piece endgames, with pawns

Tags: endgame, rook-and-minor-endgame

Where can I find resources on how to play these types of endgames?

I've done a google search, but all I came up with was repeated results for a Fritz Trainer dvd, and a similar, unanswered, question on chess.com. Silman and Dvoretsky's endgame books do not cover them.

I'm currently playing a correspondence game, and trying to come up with a plan before I blunder or drift into a worse position.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Fundamental-Chess-Endings-Karsten-M%C3%BCller/dp/1901983536

Comment: There are several good examples and analysis in Shereshevsky's classic, Endgame Strategy.

Comment: Can someone explain the votes to close? OP is asking about a specific type of endgame, how is this question "too broad"?

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen I suspect at least one of them is in retaliation for a recent attempt to clarify a question that didn't go well, with me being called a troll. I also got a couple of down votes shortly afterwards.

Comment: You can go for a plan in rook or bishop endgame sometimes, but don't expect there's much strategy in endgames you are asking. It's mainly about tactics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(practical) Endgame resources: What's next after josh waitzkin's series in chessmaster?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/practical-endgame-resources-whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-series-in-chess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of endgames often occur in practice, so even if it is difficult to give hard and fast rules about them, it is well worth spending some time studying them.

The book [Practical Endgame Play - beyond the basic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857445554) by Flear is quite decent and spends 4 chapters (111 pages) on the endgame Rook and minor piece vs Rook and minor piece. It is a relatively easy read.

[Fundamental Chess Endings](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983536) by Müller and Lamprecht (as mentioned in the comments) is an endgame book of high quality, but only has 9 pages on this particular type of endgame.

Another book I like is [Endgame Secrets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/071348165X) by Lutz. About half the examples in this book feature the material balance you ask about. This book is probably aimed towards stronger players as the analysis is very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Encyclopedia of .  These are big volumes.
here is a link to one for pawns: [https://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedia-Chess-Endings-Pawn/dp/B007W8C4R0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007W8C4R0) 
But there are ones for Queen endgames, Rook + minor piece, etc.